# How to drag an image inside a canvas without redrawing shapes on the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I have a lot map image which has some number of plats. I placed the image in a canvas and able to draw polygons over the map image to mark the boundaries. After drawing a shape if I drag the image the shape disappears. So I need to redraw it. But I want the shapes to be with the image during the drag. It should not disappear. Is there any way to do it without redrawing the shape?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this, but your use case is very important here--can you share a [mcve] showing your current code? Thanks!

Comment: maybe use a library like [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com) to get these results and build on top of it?